# Symfony ManyToMany generate 2 tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I've two entities: **Product** and **Category**. This should be many-to-many relationship, because each categories can have many products, and each products can belongs to many categories. And, I need to access Categories from my Product and also need to know the products of a category.

So here is my code.

In my Product Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $categories;
```

In my Category Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $products;
```

The problem is, when I do a scheme update, Doctrine generate 2 tables:
`category_product` and `product_category`

How can I make it work with dealing with one table?

Comment: Have you read this ?  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
 */
private $categories;
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mapped_by="categories")
 * @ApiSubresource
 */
private $products;
```

Don't forget to initialize in the constructor, and `cascade="persist"` is default AFAIK

Comment: What is the problem when you don't initialize in the constructor? When i don't do this, everything seems to work as well.

Comment: doctrine return a Collection of objects, initialize the Collection in constructor permit to always have a Collection instead of null and you can develop your app more easily